# Liferay 5.2: extending BaseFriendlyURLMapper, populateParams() method not triggered

Tags: liferay, friendly-url

I tried to extend BaseFriendlyURLMapper under Liferay5.2 - Jboss4.2 application server... No problem with buildPath() method, but I can not understand when populateParams() is triggered... not even in debug mode

this is my `liferay-portlet.xml`

```xml
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>bookingInterface</portlet-name>
    <configuration-action-class>my.package.MyConfiguration
    </configuration-action-class>

    <!-- -->

    <instanceable>false</instanceable>

    <private-request-attributes>false</private-request-attributes>
    <private-session-attributes>false</private-session-attributes>
    <friendly-url-mapper-class>
        my.package.MyFriendlyURLMapper
    </friendly-url-mapper-class>
    <use-default-template>true</use-default-template>
    <restore-current-view>true</restore-current-view>
</portlet>
```

this is `MyFriendlyURLMapper.java`

```java
public class MyFriendlyURLMapper extends BaseFriendlyURLMapper{

private static final String _PORTLET_ID="myPortlet_WAR_myPortlet";
private static final String _PORTLET_MAPPING = "myPortlet";
private static final String _LIFECYCLE_RENDER = "0";
private static final String _LIFECYCLE_ACTION = "1";
private static final String _LIFECYCLE_RESOURCE = "2";

public String getPortletId() {
    return _PORTLET_ID;
}
public String getMapping() {
    return _PORTLET_MAPPING;
}

public String buildPath(LiferayPortletURL portletURL) {
    String friendlyURLPath = null;
    String portletId = portletURL.getPortletId();
        String action = GetterUtil.getString(portletURL.getParameter("action"));
    if(action.equals("step1")){
        System.out.println("step1" );

    }
    friendlyURLPath = StringPool.FORWARD_SLASH +getMapping()
                    + StringPool.FORWARD_SLASH + action
                     ;

        if (Validator.isNotNull(friendlyURLPath)) {

            //parametri da rimuovere dalla portleturl

            portletURL.addParameterIncludedInPath("action");

            portletURL.addParameterIncludedInPath("p_p_id");
            portletURL.addParameterIncludedInPath("p_p_lifecycle");
            portletURL.addParameterIncludedInPath("p_p_state");
            portletURL.addParameterIncludedInPath("p_p_mode");
            portletURL.addParameterIncludedInPath("p_p_col_id");
            portletURL.addParameterIncludedInPath("p_p_col_count");

        } 


    }
    // return orignal unformatted url
    return friendlyURLPath;

}



public void populateParams(String friendlyURLPath, Map<String, String[]> parameterMap) {
    System.out.println(friendlyURLPath );
    System.out.println(parameterMap.size() );


}
```

any hint?

Answer (score 0):

populateParams() does the reverse of buildPath(). It is called when a friendly URL needs to be converted to the original Liferay portlet URL. It should be triggered, for example, when you go to the friendly URL. Then Liferay will call the populateParams() to build a Liferay URL (you know, the long one with a plenty of parameters).

In short, buildPath() is used to generate a friendly looking URL and populateParams() is used to build a Liferay styled portlet URL. This way, the mapping works both ways.

Comment: Here is also a great explanation of how friendly URLs are handled in Liferay 5. http://www.devatwork.nl/2010/04/seo-friendly-urls-for-liferay-portlets/

Comment: This is clear... the problem, in my portlet, is that populateParams isn't triggered, so portletUrl is written in friendly mode and never re-converted (by populateParams) on click...

Comment: That is weird indeed. Just a quick try: remove the line breaks when specifying the friendly mapper in liferay-portlet.xml. It might not get registered at all (Liferay sees an empty string). If not helpful, could you post the .war file perhaps?